# Installing ArcPy (from ArcGIS Pro) with Anaconda?

Tags: arcpy, installation, arcgis-pro, anaconda

I would like to use ArcPy from ArcGIS Pro with my Anaconda install.

ArcGIS Pro installs a 64bit python3 version of arcpy. How do I add this version of arcpy to my anaconda 64bit python3 install?

And if I need to find the arcpy version on the file system to do this, how do I find it? and how do I know that I've found the correct file?

Comment: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/116150 Do you have a "[ArcGIS Pro Install Folder]\Support\ArcGISPro.pth" or "[ArcGIS Pro Install Folder]\Support\Python\ArcGISPro.pth"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With ArcGIS Pro 1.3, conda is included as part of the base Python installation. If you can wait, this is probably the easiest way to integrate the two as the shipped environment will provide a consistent set of packages used by the application.

If you'd like to work with your Anaconda environment today, you can do so but it can be problematic — you need to ensure that packages used by the application match the versions installed into your Anaconda environment. Particularly, the NumPy version must match the version used within Pro. You can then try adding the `ArcGISPro.pth` file as mentioned in the commends by @Luke. Curtis Price has also written up an [extensive guide](https://my.usgs.gov/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=540116867) on integrating Anaconda with ArcGIS that you may find of use.

Comment: awesome link to the Curtis' work. It's very easy to mess things up with conda and ArcGIS Desktop; I found it was easier just to install packages with pip (`jupyter` etc). `Pandas, numpy, scipy` are part of 10.4 version. `virtualenv` will handle diff. env. nicely. Out of curiosity, what would other advantages be with anaconda except letting admin installing stuff more easily?